# I'm struggling to create a new comment the correct way on the frontend ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create a comment with this addComment action where I want to use the input text as the comment text and do a save to create the comment.

I couldn't connect the input box to comment.body because the position of this code does not have the comment model available.

I created a body field on the item model so I connect item.body to the text box and then use this as the comment.body when creating the comment which seems very wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this the correct way?

```
<form class="comments-list__add-comment add-comment" action="">
  {{input type="text" class="add-comment__input" name="" value=item.body placeholder="Please add a comment"}}
  <button {{action "addComment" item}} type="button" class="btn add-comment__submit" name="button">Add comment</button>
</form>

addComment(item){
  const plan = item.get('plan');
  const text = this.get('item.body');
  const currentUserName = plan.get('appConfig.currentUser');
  const currentUserId = plan.get('appConfig.currentUserId');
  const itemid = item.id;
  if(text.trim() !== ''){
    let comment = this.get('item.store').createRecord('comment', {
      body: text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      commentableId: itemid,
      commentableType: 'Plan',
      unread: true,
      commenterName: currentUserName,
      commenterId: currentUserId
    });
    item.get('comments').pushObject(comment);
    comment.save();
    item.set('displayAddCommentForm', false);
    this.set('item.body', '');
  }
},
```

Comment: could you split the code up into the files where you put it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `comment` record in your route and assign it to a controller property.  Then you can bind your template to the controller's comment property, like this:

### route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('comment', this.store.createRecord('comment');
  }
});
```

### template

```
{{input value=comment.body}}
```

Then, in your Route's `save` method:

```
let comment= this.controller.get('comment');
// the remainder of your save should follow...
// At this point, comment.body should have the text entered by user
```